# I want to run xcode project on OS X Yosemite as if it was run on OS X El Capitan

Tags: xcode, macos

I am working on a Mac project and have xcode v 7.0.0, OS X Yosemite. But when my unit tests are running under OS X El Capitan, there are some methods that returns another number, and my tests fails. 
 My **Build Setting** > **Base SDK** is setted to OS X 10.11.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know if there’s a better way, but we use virtualization ([VMware](https://www.vmware.com)) to test on older OS X releases. It’s a heavyweight solution, but it’s almost perfect in reproducing the behaviour of a real Mac with the older OS X version, which is crucial for testing.